# SSH PAM captcha handling with Java libraries

Tags: ssh, captcha, jsch, openssh, pam

I have been using JSch & Ganymed libraries for establishing SSH connections through my Java code. Due to security reasons, SSH connections are nowadays asking for a PAM **CAPTCHA** before authentication. AFAIK, JSch & Ganymed libraries do not have API's for handling CAPTCHA. Though through SSH keys (`authorized_keys` file at server side) I can skip it.

But I am curious that, is there a way to handle or skip the SSH PAM CAPTCHA through Java code?

Answer (score 0):

With the SSH the PAM uses "keyboard-interactive" authentication method.

In JSch, you have to implement the [`UIKeyboardInteractive`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html) to handle keyboard-interactive challenges.

See their [`UserAuthKI.java`](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthKI.java.html) example.